# matlab 3d pdf export

Tags: matlab, 3d, export

I'm trying to use this script:

```
inv_bisbos_pil16div;
fig2u3d(ax,fname,'-pdf',0);
```

However I receive these errors:

```
Error using single_mesh_resource_str (line 45)
#colors ~= #points and #colors ~= #faces and #colors not empty.

Error in populate_mesh_resource_str (line 28)
    cur_mesh_resource = single_mesh_resource_str(faces, points, face_vertex_data, i);

Error in fig2idtf (line 63)
mesh_resources = populate_mesh_resource_str(faces, surface_vertices, face_vertex_data);

Error in fig2u3d (line 233)
fig2idtf(fname,...

Error in PDF3DGenerator (line 9)
fig2u3d(ax,fname,'-pdf',0);
```

the script `inv_bisbos_pil16div` implements the following instructions:

```
fname ='test1';
figure('Name',fname);

hold on

K1=convhull(e_Se);
tr=[];

tr=trisurf(K1,e_Se(:,1),e_Se(:,2),e_Se(:,3));  

set(tr,'EdgeColor', 'g', 'FaceColor','r','facealpha',1.0);

%% view
axis(gca,'equal')
axis(gca,'tight')
view(gca,3)
ax=gca;
```

`e_Se` is a provided set of points.

Comment: post an actual example of the set of points

Comment: e_Se0=[-454.836,1.0364,-13.782;
-436.851,-0.243995,-14.0424;
-482.933,2.85375,-14.4825;
-484.262,2.91734,-14.6319;
-484.506,2.9265,-14.6717;
-484.58,2.92887,-14.6851;
-518.704,3.02315,-15.3921;
-518.62,3.01998,-15.3748;
-518.237,3.00362,-15.3126;
-510.287,2.53725,-14.8155;
-463.053,-0.725629,-15.2241;
-429.813,-0.844969,-14.6471;
-429.791,-0.851159,-14.6769;
-429.787,-0.852324,-14.6837;
-429.781,-0.851157,-14.6769;
-429.783,-0.846049,-14.6517;
-429.915,-0.822243,-14.574;
-431.633,-0.651792,-14.3238;
-484.235,2.91712,-14.6322;
-484.665,2.93188,-14.7065;
];

Comment: e_Se1=[-484.754,2.93392,-14.7263;
-518.91,3.0289,-15.4415;
-518.92,3.029,-15.4431;
-518.909,3.02863,-15.4382;
-518.836,3.02646,-15.4167;
-517.008,2.93493,-15.1758;
-463.308,-0.780309,-15.445;
-463.308,-0.786568,-15.49;
-429.835,-0.857882,-14.7315;
-429.83,-0.857951,-14.7324;
-429.818,-0.857608,-14.7277;
-429.795,-0.856426,-14.7148;
-429.762,-0.851006,-14.6768;
-430.087,-0.791965,-14.5168;
-484.597,2.93045,-14.6979;
-484.786,2.93471,-14.7378;
-512.619,3.02479,-15.4403;
-518.976,3.02987,-15.4618;
-518.988,3.02993,-15.4643;
-518.995,3.02991,-15.4646;
-519.134,3.01688,-15.4621;
];

Comment: e_Se2=[-466.132,-0.796537,-16.147;
-464.852,-0.820491,-16.5511;
-429.877,-0.858956,-14.7543;
-429.868,-0.858922,-14.7527;
-429.855,-0.858797,-14.7489;
-429.711,-0.846002,-14.6768;
-484.78,2.93478,-14.7449;
-484.855,2.93555,-14.76;
-512.666,3.02515,-15.4564;
-519.016,3.03007,-15.4763;
-519.015,3.03007,-15.4761;
-519.029,3.03006,-15.4793;
-521.805,3.02116,-16.119;
-522.162,3.01866,-16.1906;
-522.294,3.00592,-16.2653;
-464.982,-0.819832,-16.5883;
-464.907,-0.820605,-16.5733;
-464.884,-0.820702,-16.5681;
-429.903,-0.859123,-14.7672;
];

Comment: e_Se3=[-429.902,-0.859123,-14.7669;
-429.89,-0.859108,-14.764;
-429.873,-0.859041,-14.7599;
-429.842,-0.858737,-14.7516;
-430.111,-0.848127,-14.8443;
-484.902,2.93477,-14.7921;
-484.911,2.93544,-14.7822;
-512.222,2.99639,-16.6654;
-521.805,3.02099,-16.1993;
-521.818,3.02086,-16.2031;
-522.029,3.01939,-16.2124;
-521.62,3.00323,-16.6183;
-521.323,2.93834,-16.822;
-465.842,-0.805769,-16.638;
-464.976,-0.819758,-16.5954;
-464.93,-0.820344,-16.5842;
-464.909,-0.820519,-16.5792;
-429.93,-0.858978,-14.779;
-429.923,-0.85896,-14.7786;
-431.91,-0.763979,-15.0674;
-512.27,2.98827,-16.7427;
];

Comment: e_Se4=[-512.27,2.99452,-16.6977;
-518.605,3.00029,-16.7037;
-521.592,3.00398,-16.6111;
-521.614,3.0028,-16.624;
-521.647,2.99738,-16.662;
-519.777,2.79816,-17.015;
-466.203,-0.792437,-16.7037;
-465.098,-0.816928,-16.6267;
-465.009,-0.818975,-16.607;
-464.976,-0.819548,-16.5994;
-462.395,-0.812466,-16.6938;
-430.009,-0.85768,-14.8051;
-430.082,-0.85551,-14.8266;
-465.935,-0.305413,-17.3119;
-511.927,2.93725,-16.8964;
-512.287,2.9824,-16.7726;
-518.648,2.99466,-16.7524;
-518.654,2.99349,-16.7592;
-518.652,2.98839,-16.7844;
-521.495,2.96861,-16.7648;
-514.559,2.39037,-17.2965;
];

Comment: e_Se5=[-467.505,-0.729063,-16.8534;
-465.5,-0.802395,-16.7013;
-462.686,-0.804376,-16.7575;
-462.612,-0.806743,-16.7441;
-462.611,-0.806621,-16.7448;
-457.602,-0.788142,-16.7526;
-457.986,-0.771778,-16.8148;
-490.373,1.10394,-17.6542;
-457.622,-0.768939,-15.4325;
-457.577,-0.767354,-15.4118;
-512.265,2.99531,-16.6881;
-512.308,2.98859,-16.7428;
-521.083,2.99389,-16.5575;
];

e_Se=[e_Se0;e_Se1;e_Se2;e_Se3;e_Se4;e_Se5];
I'm sorry but I had to split the matrix. Hope you could help me. Best regards